# Is categorical logic the same as predicate logic

Tags: logic, syllogism, predicate-logic

In philosophical logic, categorical logic is the logic that deals with the logical relationship between categorical statements. I wonder if categorical logic is considered the same as predicate logic (first-order logic) in formal logic.

Comment: Note that there's a terminology overload here which I've seen lead to confusion before: "categorical logic" (or sometimes "categorial logic") can also refer to approaches to logic via category theory. (For that matter, "categorical" *also* has a separate meaning in model theory.)

Comment: 'Categorical syllogism' is the right name; 'categorical logic' only adds confusion if used in that sense -few tend to that rubbish.

Comment: No they are NOT IDENTICAL. One form must be translated into the other. Also the purposes are distinct. LOGIC as almost all young teens call it these days 98 percent of the time means MATHEMATICAL LOGIC aka discrete mathematics. There are real world cases where those techniques will fail. Categorical syllogisms are designed in a specific wording structure to eliminate rhetoric & emotions. Math will tell you logic is about validity. Philosophy focuses on Soundness. Validity alone often fails in the real world.

Comment: It is a subset of; see [Monadic predicate calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monadic_predicate_calculus)

Answer (score 2):

As @TankutBeygu notes in his comment, there is a terminological difficulty here. "Categorical logic" sounds like a general class of logical systems that deals with categories, but the only example of categorical logic is the logic of the syllogism, which is a specific formalism invented by Aristotle.

A syllogism is made of three statements, each of which has one of the following four forms of categorical sentence.

- All A is B.
- No A is B.
- Some A is B.
- Some A is not B.

In English, you have to modify the sentences a bit to have them sound right (I don't know if this is necessary in Greek). For example, you wouldn't say "All blue is colored", you would say "Everything blue is colored". With that, here is a syllogism:

> Everything blue is colored.

> Everything colored is extended in space.

> Everything blue is extended in space.

This is a syllogistic proof. The first two statements are the premises and the third is the conclusion. You can see that this is a very limited form of proof. It can't handle an argument with more than two premises (except by chaining them in pairs), it can't handle logical connectives such as "A and B", "A or B", or "A implies B", and it can't handle general relations. You can translate every categorical sentence into predicate calculus like this:

All A is B --> (exists x.A(x)) and (forall x.A(x)->B(x))

No A is B --> (exists x.A(x)) and (forall x.A(x)->not B(x))

Some A is B --> exists x.A(x) and B(x)

Some A is not B --> exists x.A(x) and not B(x)

However, there is no way to translate the following predicate logic sentences into categorical sentences:

forall x.A(x) -> (B(x) or C(x))

forall x,y. A(x,y) -> B(x)

Therefore, the syllogism is strictly less powerful than predicate logic. One of the motivations for inventing predicate logic is that syllogisms are not powerful enough to do mathematics.

Comment: There is one problem here in your answer. You can't form premises any kind of way you like. There are strict rules in categorical syllogisms. This is what most people either fail to mention or they are ignorant of these strict rules. Here is one most people are not aware of: the subject of a premise must be a direct noun or noun phrase. The same goes for the predicate. The purpose of syllogisms is to reduce the chance of deception. We do not do this just for kicks or fun as if there is nothing else to do. Predicate logic doesn't do this. It tries to imitate how we speak. Big difference

Comment: You should eliminate any adverbs or adjectives in all premises and then see how deception is close to impossible or is impossible itself.

Comment: You also made a mistake about there being more than two premises. Where did you get that from? There are chain argument forms in categorical syllogisms. See Sorities, Ephicherema, Enthymes, Polly syllogisms, etc. The idea here again is a battle against Rhetoric which was common in Socrates, Plato, & Aristotle's  life times. Mathematical logic works with Rhetorical phrases were people seem to word premises any kind of way & they leave the window open for a convenient switch in the context of a premise if the arguer uses Rhetoric. Mathematical logic is symbolic logic. It must use connectives.

Comment: @Logikal, first, It is not a "problem" if my answer doesn't mention a special rule followed by a tiny minority of writers on the topic, and your use of the word "ignorant" was offensive. I don't know what set you off, but please keep the personalities out of it. Second, I did mention chains of syllogisms in my answer. Third, your comments about mathematical logic make no sense. Maybe you are using some peculiar terminology of your own, but if so, you are going to have to explain it if you want people to understand you.

Comment: You explicitly stated"it can't handle an argument with more than two premises.  . . " which seems edited now.  This statement is false. For every two premises there is a conclusion whether you see it physically written or not. There are also times where premises are hidden. These are not covered in Mathematical logic. What do you mean my comments about Mathematical logic make no sense especially when you provide no reason or evidence of your claim. What did I state about Mathematical logic that made no sense? I did not call you ignorant I referred to students not knowing logic is not math.

Comment: @Logikal, I did not edit it. My original answer included the part in parenthesis which you left out in your quote. The statement is not false. A syllogism can only have two premises. A syllogistic argument can chain syllogisms together as I noted in the part you did not quote. If a premise is hidden, then you don't have a syllogism. You seem to be complaining that my answer was not a complete encyclopedic entry on Aristotelian logic.

Comment: @Logikal, As to your comment on math, what didn't make sense is saying that mathematical logic "works with rhetorical phrases" (not according to the normal meaning of "rhetorical"), that "people seem to word premises any kind of way" (not true, there are formal rules), that "they leave the window open for a convenient switch in the context of a premise" (not according to the usual meaning of "context"). Also, you seem to equivocate between "mathematical logic" as formal logic studied mathematically and "mathematical logic" as the logic used in mathematics. Two different topics.

Comment: Please explain the rationale that because you don't see a premise then it doesn't qualify as a syllogism. If that were true the Enthymes or Epicheriema would not be included in categorical syllogisms. Do you study math. Your explanations are a bit off context in philosophy --unless you are in the new set of philosophy people because they must learn Mathematical logic. So they will have that same mind set also. Older school philosophy people are different. You did not state nouns had to be used in a syllogism for subjects and predicates.Aristotelian logic has details not common to modern people

Comment: No you are sounding as if there is no distinct field specifically called "MATHEMATICAL LOGIC ". It is not called just LOGIC as some people here like to use. Stop denying there is a specific name for using the famous connectives. There is absolute proof this topic called MATHEMATICAL LOGIC exists. There are too many books specifically titled those words in the title. Aristotelian logic predates Mathematical logic by thousands of years. Mathematical logic was invented in the 19th century around 1845 to 1950 time frame. It didn't exist prior to that. You don't recognize the topic as distinct?

Comment: @Logikal, Do you know what the word "equivocate" means? Please read my comment again. I did not deny that there is a distinct field called mathematical logic. It is a topic I am rather familiar with. What I said is that you seem to sometimes mean one thing by the phrase and sometimes something else.

Comment: @Logikal, If by "the new set of philosophy people" you mean modern philosophy which began with Descartes), then yes, I'm a student of modern philosophy. So are roughly 99.9% of all English speakers who are students of philosophy. If you want to make a point about Classical or Medieval philosophy, then it is incumbent on you to express yourself in a way that the 99.9% will understand you.

Comment: I know what equivocation means. You need to demonstrate how you came up with the two contexts you seem to find. Mathematical logic is a FIELD OF STUDY & that is the only context I used the term. What you may be referring to is the use of the words. Math has changed the contexts of many terms already used in Philosophy. The same words, same spelling, same pronunciation but different meanings. Tautology is one. Contradiction is another. There is a list. People will be confused if they are learning Mathematical logic when they run into people using the same words a different way.

Comment: @Logikal, Also, "mathematical logic" (the branch of mathematics) may only be a couple of centuries old, but the logic used in mathematics goes back before Aristotle, and Aristotle's logic has never been able to deal with it.

Comment: Prove it. Evidence shows Mathematical logic was not uniform until the 19th century.  Are you a math person? Seems like the math ideology that a billion math people use. You do understand mathematical logic vocabulary is not universal outside of a classroom right? That is validity is not always real world applicable as it fails in many cases. Math teaches logic is about validity. Philosophy focused at one time on soundness. The mathematicans changed stuff that millions of people don't seem to be aware the math people CHANGED information. This leads to confusion.

Comment: @Logikal, if you were referring to the field of mathematical logic in your comment, then it is even more opaque than I at first thought. If you had meant the logic used by mathematicians, then "rhetoric" would at least have some relevance to the topic, but if you are talking about mathematical logic, the field, then bringing up relevance is just odd.

Comment: @Logical, If you think the logic of syllogism is capable of handling the logic of mathematics, then I suggest you try to prove a couple of Euclid's theorems using syllogisms. Math isn't an ideology. I don't know what it would mean for a vocabulary to "not be universal outside of a classroom". Lots of theoretical results are not real-world applicable, but not because it fails, just because it doesn't apply. I still have no idea what you mean in half of your sentences. Are you a native speaker of English?

Comment: You are now denying that Mathematical logic entertains Rhetoric.  Look how you worded your syllogism. Aristotelian rules do not allow those types of wording. In your answer you listed the only so called sentences. Your example doesn't use any of those alleged sentences. I say alleged sentences because philosophy knows the distinction between sentences, statements & propositions. Aristotelian logic requires strictly all language gets TRANSFOMED into Aristotle propositions ( the a, e, I, o propositions you called sentences). Mathematical logic entertains how people speak. You can't deny this.

Comment: @Logikal, OK, now I understand at least part of the problem. You have no idea what mathematical logic is. That is why what you say about it never seems to make sense.

Comment: Why would you say that? Show me a logic that has the famous five connectives that is not Mathematical logic.You tell me what you think Mathematical logic is since you claim I do not know what it is.The reason to you math people my use of common words is unfamiliar is because I AM NOT A MATH PERSON.  I studied Philosophy which has that word in this forum. It is a Philosophy forum but yet many people come here with Mathematical logic words as if all people know it. Mathematics has changed many words that is why you don't seem to follow what I am saying. My point is there is a context difference.

Comment: @Logikal, mathematical logic is a field of mathematics. You are, as I suggested several comments up, using the word to refer to logic used by mathematicians. I don't know what five famous connectives you have in mind (there are sixteen, of which four are prominent), but those connectives are used frequently in informal logic, not just in mathematical logic. Furthermore, this sort of predicate logic is used by practically all philosophers today who use logic; it is not peculiar to mathematics.

Comment: I would say about half of the common words are incorrect in Mathematics when they allegedly speak about logic.  Today these days I realize most young people are being brain washed.They think logic has always been part of Mathematics since the Pharohs ruled Egypt.Who is lying to you?  Mathematical logic was unified in the 19th century. There is no evidence absolutely none about there being a unified Mathematical logic prior 1845.  Someone post evidence since many people are spreading that rumor math & logic were always together. I try not to use the word LOGIC anymore & use deductive reasoning

Comment: You know the five connectives I mean. They are the and, or, the arrow for if . . .then . . , the biconditional & the negation (tilde). Predicate logic is MATHEMATICAL LOGIC. Any for of those connectives clearly represent a form of Mathematical logic. Clearly we can see Aristotelian logic did not use them. Prior to Mathematical logic there was JUST ARISTOTELIAN LOGIC.   Show me evidence otherwise. The logic you claim Philosophy uses is MATHEMATICAL LOGIC. This term was also used by Bertrand Russell who was a PHILOSOPHER. He was a main proponent to claim logic can be identical to Mathematics.

Comment: If you are telling me that there is such a topic with the name Mathematical logic which differs from how I defined it is only adding to more confusion. This would clearly help math student keep running the narrative the Mathematical logic always existed for thousands of years with zero evidence. Who is teaching this? There was a time all logic courses in the USA were taught in the Philosophy department. Today so many so called LOGIC classes are taught in both MATH & PHILOSOPHY which are not identical I am shocked that most people here seem to be non philosophy students & mostly math.

Comment: @Logikal, you just do not understand what people are saying. No one claims that the propositional calculus predates the nineteenth century, what people mean when they talk about the logic of mathematics going back millennia is not a formal system of logic, but a method of reasoning. This method is fully mature already in Euclid, and, critically, the logic of Aristotle was not powerful enough to express this reasoning. I am too exhausted to try to clear up all of your other misunderstandings, so I'm going to to quit with that.

Comment: My misunderstandings? Will you at least admit you are using Mathematical logic terminology which you already claimed is in mathematics and not Philosophy. You are in a non mathematics forum explaining or expecting philosophy people to automatically know Mathematical logic terms that also used differently in Philosophy? Make it make sense. What you meant to say is that mathematics uses a portion of DEDUCTIVE REASONING which is NOT LOGIC. Math is a small part of deductive reasoning. Deductive reasoning is the larger circle & Mathematical logic is a smaller circle inside the larger circle.

Comment: I am using the terminology of logic in the way that it is normally used in modern philosophy.

Comment: Well if modern philosophers are trained by faculty in the Mathematics department then yes I can see that. There is no question the graduates today are totally distinct from how the same terminology was used over 50 years ago in Philosophy. You mean your context has been exactly what Mathematicians teach since what people call logic is MATHEMATICAL LOGIC. There was a time when the same topic in philosophy was referred to as DEDUCTIVE REASONING. It was also referred to as DEDUCTIVE LOGIC. It seems now people just made it LOGIC for short. There are different types of logic. Naming 1 you use helps

Answer (score 0):

Predicate logic is usually understood these days as what is called "predicate logic" in mathematical logic. As such, it is certainly not identical with Aristotle's syllogistic. It is literally antinomic with it.

I believe there would be no problem in principle working out a formal model of Aristotle's syllogistic, although I think nobody has done it yet.

One interesting question would be how you extend predicate logic, with typical expressions such as Socrates is mortal, to relational logic, for example Romeo loves Juliet.

Comment: N.B. There are studies in this direction. The best known is  Łukasiewicz, Jan (1951, 1957). Aristotle's Syllogistic from the Standpoint of Modern Formal Logic, 2nd edition. Oxford: Clarendon Press.

Comment: @TankutBeygu Yes, and not just him. There are more recent works, for example John Corcoran's. But, yes, while all these people say interesting things, they don't actually produce any actual relational syllogistic.

Comment: How about https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232025708_An_intensional_Leibniz_semantics_for_Aristotelian_logic?

Comment: @DavidGudeman Thanks, I'll try to look at it, but we would already know if he had succeeded.